# Why image of a line in complex plane is a circle in the Riemann sphere?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-geometry, stereographic-projections

Let $ax+by+c=0$ be a line in complex plane. If $\pi$ be the stereographic progection, then since

$$\pi^{-1}(x_1,x_2,x_3)=\left(\frac{2x_1}{2-x_3},\frac{2x_2}{2-x_3}\right)$$

we have

$$a\left(\frac{2x_1}{2-x_3}\right)+b\left(\frac{2x_2}{2-x_3}\right)+c=0$$

or equivalently

$$2ax_1+2bx_2-cx_3=-2c$$

But this is clearly the equation of a plane in $\mathbb R^3$ and not a circle.
So could someone explain for me what's the problem? Thanks!

Comment: and can you tell what the intersection of a plane and a sphere looks like...?

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki Circle or ellipse

Comment: it's actually always a circle (or a point, or the empty set)

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki and then how this is related to my problem?

Comment: you find that your line in the complex plane lies in a plane in $\mathbb R^3$ when you pull back by $\pi$. but it is also in a sphere (embedded in $\mathbb R^3$). so it's in a circle of that sphere, and you're done.

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki But we don't know if this plane has intersection with the Riemann sphere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Stereographic projection* in the first place is a geometrically defined map. You are given a plane $C$ and a sphere $S\subset{\mathbb R}^3$. Then you choose a projection center $N\in S$ and match the points of $S\setminus\{N\}$ with those of $C$ by drawing rays through $N$. If $\ell\subset C$ is a line then the rays $N\vee Z$ for $Z\in\ell$ constitute a plane, and this plane intersects $S$ in a circle passing through $N$.